# Нужно возвращать std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> а я возвращаю QJsonObject, что делать?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Как исправить  ошибку? У меня есть функция

```
 std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject> Archiver::serialise(const Component* component)
 {
    JSONVisitor visitor;
    component->visit(&visitor);

    return visitor.jsonData();
 }
```

visitor.jsonData(); -  это просто QJsonObject

И выдает ошибку

```
  'return': cannot convert from 'const QJsonObject' to
  'std::unique_ptr<QJsonObject,std::default_delete<_Ty>>
```

И я  нек знаю как  это исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return std::make_unique<QJsonObject>(visitor.jsonData())
```